# Max version with both values of another Column

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I want to present the last version of a table with both values on another.

```
Version | Value
12      | ORANGE
11      | ORANGE
11      | BANANA
10      | ORANGE
11      | BANANA
```

The result should be

```
11      | ORANGE
11      | BANANA
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is there any logic applied to get this result?

Comment: I want a select that shows both rows with max version and both values.

Comment: But why Orange is 11 and not 12?

Comment: You mean the max version where both values exist? Are those values known or any values?

Comment: that's another problem (The existence on 11 and not 12)

I must delete all other row except the max version with both BANANA and ORANGE.

And BANANA and ORANGE are know values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should works

```
SELECT * 
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE VERSION IN (
    SELECT MIN(VERSION) -- GET MIN VERSION FROM MAX
    FROM (
       SELECT MAX(VERSION) as VERSION, 
       FROM TABLE
       GROUP BY VALUE)
    )
  )
```

This trick return you min version from Max versions, it works only if both banana and orange share exact version number.
This means that if Orange skips a versione (from 11 to 13 withou 12) and banana is exactly 12, it won't work.

Comment: It will also fail when you add a new row `13      | BANANA`

Comment: Agree, maybe we could use @dnoeth reply as correct, because his script gonna find exact the lower version in common with Banana and Orange. We could change also the Having clause with a new query on distinct value element instead of just 2

Answer (score 0):

This should match your description:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE Version IN
 (
   SELECT MAX(Version) OVER ()
   FROM tab
   -- WHERE Value in ('ORANGE','BANANA') ???
   GROUP BY Version
   -- HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value) -- if duplicates exist
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- only versions with two entries
 )
```